# To pass textbox value in attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have a textbox my aim is to pass textbox value through attributes please anyone help me to solve the issue.

html code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

code behind:

```
string strRegularExp = string.Empty;

if (ListOfRegularExpression != null)
{
    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < ListOfRegularExpression.Count; iRow++)
    {
        strRegularExp += ListOfRegularExpression[iRow].ToString() + "~~";
        hidRegExp.Value = strRegularExp;
        if (iRow == ListOfRegularExpression.Count - 1)
        {
            strRegularExp = strRegularExp.TrimEnd("~~".ToCharArray());
            string Field = txtField.Text.ToString();

            txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp('" + txtField.Text + ", " + hidRegExp.Value + "');"); //how to pass textbox value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are writing is going to add the attribute at the point it runs, so your txtField won't have any text.

You should be able to reference the txtField using the js `this` keyword

```
txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp(this.value, '" + hidRegExp.Value + "');");
```

You could also use the `txtField.ClientID` and some js to retrieve the textbox that way.

```
txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp(document.getElementById('"+ txtField.ClientID + "').value, '" + hidRegExp.Value + "');");
```

The reason these will work is because you are asking the javascript to get the value, not .NET, this means the value is evaluated at the onblur event, not at the moment the code is written into the attribute, where it would be empty.

Comment: i got this.value in alert

Comment: You are doing `alert('this.value')` and not `alert(this.value)`

Comment: I can get textbox value but now i cant get " + hidRegExp.Value + " this value which is already working.

Comment: Run it in debug and check the syntax of the javascript, you probably have an extra `'` or `,` or something in there. Notice in my example the hidRegExp.Value is evaluated in C#, and written into the javascript, (See the `'" + hidRegExp.Value + "'`

Comment: Can u tell me how to combine textbox value and hidRegExp.ClientID

Comment: I'd need to see more about how you've wired that up, is it a `RegularExpressionValidator`?

Comment: yes it is a regularexpression validator now i have to combine 2 id values

Comment: function ValidateRegExp(txtInput) {
       var mySplitInput = new Array();
        mySplitInput = txtInput.split(",");
      var hiddenValue = document.getElementById("<%=hidRegExp.ClientID%>").value;
       alert(txtInput);
        var mySplitResult = new Array();
        mySplitResult = RegExp.split("~~");
        var value = document.getElementById("<%=txtField.ClientID%>").value;
        alert(value);
        for (i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++) {
            
            var re = new RegExp(mySplitResult[i]);
            
        }

    }